# return value to client and then some callbacks

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

in the code below what i am trying to do is allow my client to call a wcf method on the server , return  success and then give callbacks on the current progress i.e percentage complete. The client can disconnect say after 10% and the method will continue.

On the code below though - the return "success" line causes the function to exit. The reason i want the return is so the client blocks until he knows the service has some important processing complete.

Is this possible?

```
namespace WCFService
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class WCFJobsLibrary : IWCFJobsLibrary
    {
        public String ChatToServer(string texttoServer) // send some text to the server
        {
            Logging.Write_To_Log_File("Entry", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "", "", "", 1);

            try
            {
                // Some extemely important prechecks .....
                //........
                return "success";

                // Dont care now if client disconnects but lets give them some updates as progress happens if they are still connected


                IMyContractCallBack callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyContractCallBack>();
                // Some processing .....
                callbackmethod("20% complete", callback);
                // Some processing .....
                callbackmethod("40% complete", callback);
                // Some processing .....
                callbackmethod("60% complete", callback);
                // Some processing .....
                callbackmethod("80% complete", callback);
                // Some processing .....
                callbackmethod("100% complete", callback);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "error";
            }
        }

        public void callbackmethod(string text, IMyContractCallBack somecallback)
        {
            try
            {
                somecallback.callbacktoServer(text);
            }    
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the callbacks Async and they will fire, and the method will return, but you have to place the `return` line after the callbacks are invoked.

In case of error, WCF has automatic exception handling built in, so you can just `Throw` the Exception, you don't need to return it... it can then be caught at the client. And will have more information than just "error".

Example using TPL: (using `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace, .net 4+)

```
    string yourMethod() 
    {
        // Logging

        try 
        {   
            // prechecks 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "failed" // ok as you have now if no more information is needed
            // throw; // Can also throw exception which WCF client on other end can catch
        }     

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            IMyContractCallBack callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyContractCallBack>();
            // Some processing .....
            callbackmethod("20% complete", callback);
            // Some processing .....
            callbackmethod("40% complete", callback);
            // Some processing .....
            callbackmethod("60% complete", callback);
            // Some processing .....
            callbackmethod("80% complete", callback);
            // Some processing .....
            callbackmethod("100% complete", callback);
        });
        return "success";
   }
```

Comment: im not sure i understand you - are you saying dont bother returning a success/fail?

Comment: @user1438082 Updated my answer to hopefully explain a bit better

Comment: i dont understand you - what i am actually doing is giving wcf a job to do - it does some quick prechecks and tells the client everything looks ok - then the wcf service does some work that could take an hour to complete but the client can disconnect if he wants and if not ill show a nice progress bar as to how the wcf service is getting on with the processing.

Comment: ok - so correct me if i am wrong here but what you have done is kickstarted the long process as a task and return to the client. This return should then happen in less than 0.5 of a second for example?

Comment: It should kick off the Task and return immediately, meaning the time for the method to execute should be however long it takes to do your prechecks and start the Task.

Answer (score 2):

When you `return` in a function, it will stop at that line. Nothing you put after that return will execute. In fact your compiler should have warned you about unreachable code.

Edit:

I would suggest starting a thread prior to calling return that will run the continue work and send out the update calls.

```
public String ChatToServer(string texttoServer) // send some text to the server
        {

            try
            {
                Logging.Write_To_Log_File("Entry", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "", "", "", 1);
                // Some extemely important prechecks .....
                System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(DoWork);
                thread.Start();
                //........
                return "success";

                // Dont care now if client disconnects but lets give them some updates as progress happens if they are still connected

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "error";
            }
        }

        void DoWork()
        {
            IMyContractCallBack callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyContractCallBack>();
            // Some processing .....
            callbackmethod("20% complete", callback);
            // Some processing .....
            callbackmethod("40% complete", callback);
            // Some processing .....
            callbackmethod("60% complete", callback);
            // Some processing .....
            callbackmethod("80% complete", callback);
            // Some processing .....
            callbackmethod("100% complete", callback);

        }
```

Comment: I see what you are asking, you want to know how to implement a way of doing that, not what is wrong with your code above. I will see if I can update an answer for you before I leave work.

Comment: this is the same theory as the answer by David Khaykin above - so guess both of you are correct